Merge Queries in Transform Data Power BI
I merged two tables in transform data and some of my columns have duplicate values in them now. And if I clean up the duplicates in the columns, I lose data I need to keep in other columns.
I've tried the m code:
  = let
  note = [Internal Note],
  position = Text.PositionOf(note, "B2")
in
  if position >= 0 then
    Text.Middle(note, position, 12)
  else
    null

another code attempted:
  = if Text.Contains([Internal Note], "B2") then
      Text.Middle([Internal Note], Text.PositionOf([Internal Note], "B2"), 12)
    else
      null

